# famo.us: Modify content in GridLayout

Tags: css, famo.us

is it possible to modify the content of a surface (used within GridLayout) without using CSS? For example to center the text?

Basic example:

```
    function createGrid( section, dimensions, menuData ) {
      var grid = new GridLayout({
        dimensions: dimensions
      });

      var surfaces = [];
      grid.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

      for(var i = 0; i < dimensions[1]; i++) {
          surfaces.push(new Surface({
              content: menuData[i].title,
              size: [undefined, undefined],
              properties: {
                backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                color: "white",
                textAlign: 'center',
              }
          }));
      }

      return grid;
}
```

I added the center property, but I also want to have the content in the middle of my surface. Do I have to use CSS or is there another way?
I tried adding another View/Surface within this Surface and added the align/origin modifier. Didn't work: I still had to adjust the origin/align values for the specific (browser) layout ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure about you first question, but I can answer the second one.

`text-align`helps you horizontally center your content. So the problem is how to do it vertically.

The cleanest way to do it is to set the `line-height` the same as the containing `div`'s height. In your case, there are two ways to do it:

1) calculate the height of the grid. For example, if you have a 9*9 `GridLayout` for the whole screen, then we will have `gridHeight = window.innerHeight/9`. Then you just need to add `lineHeight: gridHeight` to your properties object.

check http://jsfiddle.net/mrwiredancer/veLpbmmo/2/ for full exmaple

2) if you are not able to calculate the height of the grid beforehand, you can center a fixed-height(smaller than the grid's height) surface in the middle of the grid. For example, your `GridLayout` is contained in a dynamic view, but you're sure that your grid is no less than `20px` high. Then you can do this:

```
var container, surface, __height = 20;

for(var i = 0; i < dimensions[1]; i++) {
    container = new Container({ //View works as well
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
        }
    })

    surface = new Surface({
        content: menuData[i].title,
        size: [undefined, __height],
        properties: {
            lineHeight: __height+'px', //same as surface's height
            color: "white",
            textAlign: 'center',
        }        
    });

    container.add(new Modifier({origin: [.5, .5]})).add(surface);

    surfaces.push(container);
}
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/mrwiredancer/uxq30yp9/1/ for full example

Comment: quick addition: if you use "view = new View(...)" instead of container, the background property stops working.

Comment: @R3LYeah, becuase you cannot set properties on view. But you can sure use other ways to add a background color/surface, which is pretty easy compared to your problem